# virtualenvwrapper: mkvirtualenv is being created with my custom packages

Tags: pip, package, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I create a new environment using mkvirtualenv, the environment is created with all custom packages I've been developing.

If I run `pip show <package name>` the atribute **Location** is pointing to my local path.

Does it have to do with mkvirtualenv using my PYTHONPATH in order to install local modules on startup??

Comment: You should unset `PYTHONPATH` when using a virtual env; or even better never set it at all but always use virtual envs. Add `unset PYTHONPATH` to `~/.virtualenvs/postactivate`

Comment: @phd it worked, thanks!! But what if I do want to use a custom local library. What's the best practice? Use relative paths on my imports?

Comment: The best practice is to install all packages to every virtual env. Even if it means installing the same package into many venvs.